# Products are disappearing from categories and are coming back when we flush the cache

Tags: magento2

On Magento 2.2.7, all the products are disappearing from some of its categories so that PLP becomes blank. When we clear FPC, the products are coming back.

This issue happens at least once every day and as said above, it gets resolved when we clear FPC

Can anyone help me to solve this issue, Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Actually it is not blank. It shows "We can't find products matching the selection"

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any logic in the Blocks/ViewModels related to customers?

If so... This will result that the page will work on the first load but later on break.

Btw I suggest looking in the logs, because if the page is white on production, it means you getting some kind of PHP exception.

For clues look in

```
var/log/system.log
var/log/exception.log
```

Comment: Actually it is not blank. It shows "We can't find products matching the selection"

Comment: @Manaf P M That is the issue of indexing, your store misses the indexing process.
Check your innodb_buffer_pool_size and update it.

Check current:
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024;

Check how much is needed: 
SELECT CEILING(Total_InnoDB_Bytes*1.6/POWER(1024,3)) RIBPS FROM
    (SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) Total_InnoDB_Bytes
     FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;


This is how to set it. 
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=15032385536;

Answer (score 0):

Magento runs its indexers on a cron job and expands all of the data for each product to a flat table, so that there is a row for each product with every single attribute used. (This can lead to issues with too many attributes as MySQL/MariaDB InnoDB will only let you have a finite row size, so a few too "many" attributes or text columns will trip it up).

It decides during this indexing process to determine which products live in each category, despite this data already being in one table. It puts this into this *second* flat table, and then serves data from this. It's not very good.

If you so happen to ask the site for data regarding a product whilst it is busy generating this flat table, then it'll decide that the product doesn't exist in the category. Or, there could be an error during this "flat table" generation, and it won't show this error to you anywhere in the UI (even in the admin panel) - look in the `var/log` directory to see if there are any errors regarding this flat table generation or cron errors.

When updating a product (eg. stock status), it'll modify an attribute of a product. This leads to it flushing the entire Varnish cache because it decides that one product is related to everything else in the store, by design. The FPC will never work as intended in Magento due to the "leaves" of the data dictating what is shown or not shown (eg. the templates, or modules), with the the "saving" code having zero idea whether the cache needs to be purged or not.

It leads to a purge of the entire FPC with every single modification of an attribute for a product, eg. stock increased, backend attribute changed. There's a bug about it that seems to be getting no attention for unknown reasons (tell all your friends!): https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25670#issuecomment-576369670

You may find this affecting you even after the cache is generated, since the cache will rapidly be flushed and your server will be busy regenerating the content for everything.
But, if you are finding your server load acceptable, you should look to see what is in the flat tables themselves, or what is happening during the flat table generation.